# Sybase looping not working - interactive sql

Tags: sql, loops, database-cursor, sqlanywhere

im trying the do a simple cursor that will give me data , executing the cursor in a 5 seconds interval .

but it only shows 1 row and stop... im working on sybase interactive sql , this is the query:

```
DECLARE @codigo INTEGER 

DECLARE alarm_history_cur CURSOR FOR

SELECT AlarmHistoryID FROM DBA.AlarmHistory 
    WHERE DBA.AlarmHistory.Area = '1'
    AND DBA.AlarmHistory.DateTimeOccurred < '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'

OPEN alarm_history_cur

FETCH NEXT alarm_history_cur INTO @codigo

while @@sqlstatus = 0

BEGIN
WAITFOR DELAY    '00:00:05'


SELECT * FROM DBA.AlarmHistory WHERE AlarmHistoryID = @codigo
END

BEGIN
FETCH NEXT alarm_history_cur
INTO @codigo

END

CLOSE alarm_history_cur
DEALLOCATE CURSOR alarm_history_cur
```

thanks in advance for further help.

Update :

im using sybase central - sql anywhere ..i will let some pictures to you

-@@version picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYvTn.png)
-original select
-what actually the syntax shows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3vhm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juqnf.png)

Comment: according to the images in your latest update ... you're running Sybase `SQLAnywhere` and *not* Sybase `ASE` (as you had originally tagged the question), which negates an assumption I had that you're working on a stored proc (ie, the code you've posted is invalid when working with `ASE` in batch mode); I've updated the tags and hopefully someone with `SQLAnywhere` experience will now see this question; I also suggest you update the question to a) remove the images and replace with actual text and b) update your code to reflect the current use of a single `begin/end` block

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch` command needs to be in the same `begin/end` pair associated with the `while` loop.

Instead of this:

```
while @@sqlstatus = 0
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY    '00:00:05'
    SELECT * FROM DBA.AlarmHistory WHERE AlarmHistoryID = @codigo
END

BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT alarm_history_cur INTO @codigo
END
```

Try this:

```
while @@sqlstatus = 0
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY    '00:00:05'
    SELECT * FROM DBA.AlarmHistory WHERE AlarmHistoryID = @codigo
    FETCH NEXT alarm_history_cur INTO @codigo
END
```

Comment: it helps ...but still not doing the loop ... i only shows 1 results, i have tried with WHILE SQLCODE =0 , IF SQLSTATE = 00000 , ETC.... im using sybase 16.0 the version previus to SAP

Comment: how many rows does your main select return?  also, can you confirm you're running Sybase `ASE` and not Sybase `SQLAnywhere`?  what does `select @@version` return? (please add the answers to the question)

Comment: done . thanks for the help

Comment: I notice you added to the code in your latest update ... the `fetch` is not the last command at the end of the `while` loop (instead you've got a `print @codigo`) which may be affecting the testing of sqlcode; I'm not familiar enough with `SQLAnywhere's` WATCOM SQL dialect so if the code (*exactly* as presented in my answer) doesn't work then you'll likely need to wait for someone with `SQLAnywhere/WATCOM` experience to see the question